# matching column height in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Starting to use bootstrap 3 and would like to see if I can layout similar to vox.com.. here is a picture of what I am working towards (page layout on that site changes)

[image: sdf]

Here is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5829/

dummy code so SO will let me post:

```
 <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6
```

Obviously I have added a lot more text than necessary, but you can see the issue here:
[image: here]

You can add text to the caption on the vox site and it stays aligned... How can I get the same effect in bootstrap 3?

**UPDATE**

I can wrap the text in a class, and set the height through jquery. I need to set the overflow to hidden. This works, but I need the jquery to work only when the width is set to the mid-size desktop or [large size desktop](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). I do not want this to work when the screen is set to extra-small.. Is there a way to figure out what mode it is in through jquery?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: you want that "Right column", the one with those boxes (image + random-size text), has the maximum heigh of the image heigh of the column at left?

Comment: José Cabo: I want to the image and text to be evenly spaced like in the vox.com. So image.height * 2 + text.height * 2 = large_picture.height. I updating the answer with a jquery option that sort of gives me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change the point in which Bootstrap breaks from horizontal to stacked.  I changed yours from `sm` to `lg` which makes the break happen sooner.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5830/

Go [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) for the explanation on break points from Bootstrap.

I also think, rather than trying to hack away at the HTML/CSS, you should take a step back and think about your content.  Vox.com only has the title of an article underneath the picture, but it looks like you want to fit an entire teaser underneath the picture.  Maybe you should just put less text underneath the pictures.  That would also probably fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I did say "I have added a lot more text than necessary".. wanted to illustrate the point. I also do not want to break earlier.